# Trigger warning or compile time error for elif typo in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I had a typo (oh well, Python routine), but strangely Ruby didn't complain about it:

```
> if false; put "NO"; elif true; puts "YE"; end
=> nil

> if false; puts "NO"; elsif true; puts "YE"; end    #proper way
YE
```

I had to think about for a half a minute when I realized that it's perfectly fine Ruby syntax. Ruby interprets it as part of the command for the first `if` clause, `elif` being a command, which doesn't exist but that's not known at compilation time. Ruby didn't warn about it even with the warning flags turned on.

Is there a way to warn about these problems? Do I have to grep all my sources for such typos? Can I somehow force this to be compile time error?

(I know, it's a dynamic language, you should detect these problems with unit tests, but it's still annoying while writing new code.)

Comment: You could test your code.  Just a thought ;)

Comment: I don't see a question here. :)

Comment: "is there a way to warn about these problems"? can I somehow force this to be a "compile time" error? (note: I know it's a weird question, but I don't know any other language which allows such a typo)

Comment: Unit testing can help you here, I believe, because @SergioTulentsev is totally right in his deleted answer :D

Comment: As you say, `elif` could just be a method name, so what would Ruby warn you about? "you're calling a method with the suspicious name 'elif' inside a if-block, are your sure of that?". Of course not. Dynamic language have these drawbacks, only tests can catch them.

Comment: @tokland: yeah I am aware of unit test and that is a valid syntax (mentioned both of them in my question).. I don't think this is strictly related to the dynamic nature of the language. it's a typo in a control flow command.. can you name any other language where this wouldn't be catched?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Python and PHP, for example. http://ideone.com/XGnuT http://ideone.com/L5Qw8

Comment: @ Mladen Jablanović: http://ideone.com/7TuuW . if you have futher problems you misunderstood my question.

Comment: Would laser be capable of detecting this?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: https://github.com/michaeledgar/laser ? I will definitely try it. finally some proper advice/idea, *thank you*

Comment: @AndrewGrimm You should rewrite your comment as an answer; I didn't know laser, and it's very interesting!

Comment: the gem for laser seems to be broken :/

Answer (score 4):

In this specific case, you can choose an editor with proper syntax highlight to visually detect that's not a keyword (as `elsif` is).

For example, Kate editor has even different auto-indents for `elif` and `elsif`.